# How remove background image from UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, background-image, navigationbar, setbackground

I set `UINavigationBar` background image at root view controller, but i need to remove background image at detail view controller.

With Obj-C I use this code:

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])  
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

so when i use this code in MonoTouch:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(null, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

i receive this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullExeption  
Argument cannot be null  
Parameter name: backgroundImage
```

How can I remove the background image?

Comment: bug was reported as https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug. AFAICT `null` should be allowed in this method to remove the background.

I'll be fixing this asap for the next stable release of MonoTouch. If this is blocking you just fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll provide you an hotfix to workaround this.

**EDIT**: this is fixed and will be available in the next releases (e.g. 5.2.12 for stable)